# Send a message when user is back in teams MS botframework

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to send message to the user when he left the conversation and come back after few mins.

I want to send a message to the user everytime he opens the chatbot in teams.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to detect this in Teams, unfortunately.